# Obfuscating a cocoa touch swift framework

Tags: swift, obfuscation

So I'm currently building a cocoa touch swift framework. The problem is that it is required for me to obfuscate the code (security reasons). I have searched and found ways to obfuscate code individually(certain lines of code) or code written in objective-c. Does someone know a way to achieve this?

Comment: Security != Obscurity

Comment: When I say security it means that I don't want people to know the algorithms used for certain things

Comment: That's not possible. If others can use your framework, they will be able to figure out your algorithms, obfuscation only makes this a little harder, but definitely not impossible.

Comment: I'm aware of that. What I want is to make it a little harder as you said